# Sequelizejs error when calling associated model

Tags: node.js, angular, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize to connect with database.
I have already associated 2 models but when I get those model its showing me error.

here is my code for model

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../database/database');

const Purpose = sequelize.define('purpose', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  title: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  weighting: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  iconsUrl: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
})

module.exports = Purpose;
```

and here is how i have associated prupose with other table

```
PurposeList.belongsToMany(User, { through: PurposeUser });
User.hasMany(LifeArea);
```

when I getpupose table or add `include: [ { model: PurposeUser, as: 'projects' } ],` get this error `purposeUser is not associated to purpose!`

I am using this with Angular 7.

I am not sure is this related with angular or I am using somthing wrong.

````
exports.getUserPurpose =  (req, res, next) => {

  const userID = req.userData.userId;
  const purposesList = [];
  PurposeUser.findAll({ where: {userId: userID },
    order: ['menuOrder'],
  })
  .then(results => {
    const purposeID = [];

    results.map(res => {
      purposeID.unshift(res.dataValues.purposeId);
      purposesList.unshift({id: res.dataValues.id, purposeId: res.dataValues.purposeId, weighting: res.dataValues.weighting})
    });

    return Purpose.findAll({
      include: [ { model: PurposeUser, as: 'projects' } ],
      where: {id: purposeID},
    })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('err', err));
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup both sides of the relationship...

```
Purpose.belongsToMany(User, { through: PurposeUser, as: 'Users', foreignKey: 'purpose_id' });
User.belongsToMany(, {Purpose, {through: PurposeUser, as: 'Purposes', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
```

you need to assign some foreign key values in there as well since you probably named your columns purpose_id and user_id in PurposeUser... You had PurposeList down there but you exported it as Purpose so if you renamed those things for some reason then i can't see that...